# Record/capture Android app to animated GIF

Tags: android-studio, gif, animated-gif

I would like to capture/record the behavior of my Android app, running on an emulator and make a GIF image out it. Just like this one -

[image]

Answer (score 43, accepted):

First record video from AndroidStudio Select "Screen Record" 
[image]

and save .mp4 video then go to any online tools to convert mp4 to gif

for example
[http://ezgif.com](http://ezgif.com/video-to-gif)
and [https://cloudconvert.com](https://cloudconvert.com/gif-to-mp4)

Comment: This was been answered already in my new post, but many thanks again Sally . :)

Comment: you are welcome :) , i did not see your new post. 
i was search for direct way to capture GIF but can't find one, i shared what i do may be that help.

Comment: Thanks for this info. However "Screen Record" is disabled at my end. Any clue why it could be?

Answer (score 23):

You can [record a video](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/shell.html#screenrecord) from your emulator or real device using the standard [ADB](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb.html) tool:

```
adb shell screenrecord /sdcard/foo.mp4
```

To convert the video from MP4 to animated GIF, use [ffmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/) (again, a standard, open-source tool):

```
 ffmpeg -i foo.mp4 foo.gif
```

#### Some refinements

Given that phones nowadays have huge resolutions, a 10-second GIF can easily exceed several megabytes in size. To avoid that, record at a lower resolution by passing a `--size XXXxYYY` argument to `screenrecord`:

```
adb shell screenrecord --size 1024x768 /sdcard/compact.mp4
```

If you need to install ADB on Linux, just run `sudo apt install adb`.

If you want to trim the beginning or the end of the video, pass the following arguments to `ffmpeg`:

- `-ss 00:00:05` - where to start (e.g. 5 seconds into the video)
- `-t 00:00:10` - total duration (e.g. 10 seconds)

No need for video editors or to upload your possibly confidential screencast online.

Comment: As most of us have telephone with 16:9 display ratio and would wanna take video in portrait mode, I suggest: `--size 648x1152`.

Answer (score 23):

I found the easiest way (you have to update latest android studio & android monitory)

- Click`...` option to open More Setting on Android Monitor
- Select `Screen Record` option on left
- Click `START RECORDING` Button to record video
- Click `STOP RECORDING` Button to stop recording
- Change `WEBM` format to GIF and save it
- Enjoy...

[image]
[Watch video tutorial on YouTube](https://youtu.be/Njs_kE2bjro)

Comment: This answer is what I do as well. The only thing I would add to that answer is enabling show touches on the device as well: https://medium.theuxblog.com/enabling-show-touches-in-android-screen-recordings-for-user-research-cc968563fcb9 
I've also found that I like using giphy capture: https://giphy.com/apps/giphycapture

Answer (score 2):

The Android Monitor mentioned in the answer is [deprecated](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/am-basics.html) in the new Android Studio 3.0.

According to the [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-video.html) you can record a short video of your app like this:

1. Open an app project.
2. Run the app on **a hardware device**.
3. Click View > Tool Windows > Logcat.
4. Interact with the display on the hardware device to stage the start of the video.
5. Click Screen Record  in the left side of the Logcat window.
6. In the Screen Recorder Options dialog, set the recording options:

   - **Bit Rate:** Enter a bit rate. The default is 4 Mbps.
   - **Resolution:** Enter a width and height value in pixels. The value must be a multiple of 16. The default is the resolution of the device.
   - **Show Taps:** Enables visual feedback for taps.
7. Click Start Recording to start the recording.
8. Click Stop Recording to stop the recording.
9. In the Save As dialog, save the MP4 file.
10. In the Screen Recorder dialog, click one of the buttons to show the file location, open the recording in a player, or dismiss the dialog.

Now you can use http://ezgif.com or https://cloudconvert.com to convert the mp4 to an gif-file like Sally already mentioned.